# Any built-in method to get boundary dates for a date in day, week and month view in a calendar?

Tags: javascript

I need to send boundary dates of a selected date(from a date picker) to the server based on present view is Day or Week or Month. Example as shown given below

Ex:
If the day is 25-01-2016 and

```
1. In "Day" View I need to send :
fromDate: "25012016", 
toDate:"25012016"

2. "Week" view(consider Monday as first day of the week as the calendar view in my screen showing the same) :
fromDate: "25012016", 
toDate:"31012016"

3."Month" view:
fromDate: "01012016", 
toDate:"31012016"
```

Comment: 1 and 3 are trivial - 2 would be only slightly more complex, but Date has a `.getDay()` method that returns 0 = Sunday through to 6 = Saturday - some simple maths would make it trivial too

Comment: Ofcorse with getDay() and getDate() I tried to build methods. But I feel I am making a simple thing complex. It would be really helpful if i can do all of them in 1-2 lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for the help!

With Momentjs, I did my job.

```
// type can be "Day" or "Week" or "Month"
var getBoundaryDates = function(selecteddate, type){            
        var fromd = moment(selecteddate).startOf(type).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        var tod = moment(selectddate).endOf(type).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        if(type == 'Week') {
            var dayToSubtract = selecteddate.getDay() == 0 ? 7 : selecteddate.getDay();
            fromd = moment(new Date(selecteddate).setDate((selecteddate.getDate() - dayToSubtract) +1)).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
            tod = moment(new Date(selecteddate).setDate((selecteddate.getDate() - dayToSubtract) +7)).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        }
        return {
            fromd : fromd,
            tod : tod
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Not aware of any built in function but you can easily get

```
var currentDate = new Date();
var dayOfWeek = currentDate.getDay();
```

**Week**

```
//var currentDate = new Date();
var currentDate = new Date(2016,0,19);
var dayOfWeek = currentDate.getDay();
console.log( dayOfWeek );
dayOfWeek = (dayOfWeek + 6 )%7; //calibrate it for Monday to Sunday
currentDate.setDate( currentDate.getDate() + (-dayOfWeek ) );  //first day of week accomodating +1 for making Monday as first day
document.body.innerHTML += "<br>" + currentDate.toString();
currentDate.setDate( currentDate.getDate() + 7 ); //last day of week 
document.body.innerHTML += "<br>" + currentDate.toString();
```

**Month**

```
currentDate = new Date();
currentDate.setDate( 1 ); //first day of current month
document.body.innerHTML += "<br>" + currentDate.toString();
currentDate.setMonth( currentDate.getMonth() + 1 ); //first day of next month
currentDate.setDate( currentDate.getDate() + (-1) ); //last day of current month 
document.body.innerHTML += "<br>" + currentDate.toString();
```

Comment: your first/last day of week is wrong in the case of Sunday ... actually, it's always wrong (for a start, the question states that the week starts on MONDAY)

Comment: nope - still wrong ... Sunday(0) should be -6 for first day of week (previous Monday), and +0 for last day of week (it IS the last day of it's week)

Comment: @gurvinder372 I was also doing all these calculations and this is not even customizable(like if I have to use sunday as first day again tomorrow). And probably I even need formatted text for which again I need to add more lines. Because of all this I was xpecting a 1-2lines of code which solves my purpose. I am trying to take help of Momentjs which may do the trick!

Comment: also, once you've figured out sunday, your code `currentDate.setDate( currentDate.getDate() + (7-dayOfWeek ) );` only needs to be `currentDate.setDate( currentDate.getDate() + 6);` because you've set the date to the Monday in the previous line of code

Comment: @JaromandaX here is the working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/ogk0r8eL/ , I set the currentDate to first day but dayofweek variable was already taken before that line

Comment: change your first line of code to `var currentDate = new Date(2016,0,24);` to check if Sunday works ... you'll see it **does not** ...

Comment: @JaromandaX got it, here is the updated fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/ogk0r8eL/1/ thanks for pointing it out

Comment: @gurvinder372 - really? It's now showing Tuesday to Tuesday as being the week

Comment: @JaromandaX my bad https://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/ogk0r8eL/2/, fixed it here. anyways OP doesn't seem to want it, but it can help someone in future

Comment: @vamshikrishna - pretty ungrateful for someone who couldn't be bothered to post any code himself - you expect not only what's in the question, but ??formatted text?? in 1 or 2 lines of code - write it yourself and stop wasting peoples time here if you're going to be so selfish

Comment: @JaromandaX Be careful with ur words! I was not ungrateful to anyone and not wasting ur time! From the beginning I told u I din wanna do all those calculations using getDay() and getDate()(which I already did partly and becoz of length I stopped afterwards and posted here) as it making my method look very big and may not go to production. And I am even trying for the same and don't think I am sitting idle and seeing ur comments! Someone suggested me to use momentjs which I was working to get my solution.

Comment: `From the beginning I told u I din wanna do all those calculations using getDay() and getDate()` - no you didn't - read your QUESTION again, no mention of what you DONT want to do

Comment: `Someone suggested me to use momentjs which I was working to get my solution` - so, rather than a dozen lines of code, you'll use 3,606 lines of a library - your choice, bro

Comment: Initially I even told the same to who suggested it, but later realized that library was included in our project sometime back(for some other purpose probably). Anyhow Thanx @gurvinder372 for ur effort! I wil give u one upvote for all ur time!